# 'util.promisify is not a function' error during Cypress test when trying to run a database query

Tags: sql, node.js, database, promise, cypress

Unlike all of the 'util.promisify is not a function' threads I've seen, I am *not* explicitly trying to use the 'util.promisify' function.

What I'm trying to do is run database queries during my Cypress tests.

- Node 16.15.1
- Cypress 13.5.1
- TypeScript 5.0.2
- ts-node 10.9.1
- mssql 9.1.1

The following method works server-side, but throws a fit client-(browser)-side during Cypress tests:

Database file:

```
import sql from 'mssql';

export default class Database {
    private _databaseConnectionString;

    constructor() {
        this._databaseConnectionString = 'censored but valid connection string';
    };

    async query(query: string) {
        try {
           await sql.connect(this._databaseConnectionString);
           const result = await sql.query(query);
           return result;
        } catch (errorMessage) {
            throw new Error(`Error querying database.\n${errorMessage}`);
        }
    }
}
```

Test file:

```
import Database from "../../support/test_data/utilities/database";
const database = new Database();

describe('testing', () => {
    it('test', () => {
        const aVariable = await database.query(`select * from Users`);
    });
});
```

I isolated what triggers the exception to this line:

```
await sql.connect(this._databaseConnectionString);
```

Error:

> 1. An uncaught error was detected outside of a test:
>    TypeError: The following error originated from your test code, not from Cypress.
>
> > util.promisify is not a function
>
> When Cypress detects uncaught errors originating from your test code
> it will automatically fail the current test.
>
> Cypress could not associate this error to any specific test.
>
> We dynamically generated a new test to display this failure.

Please can anyone help? I don't know how to even start troubleshooting this. Is there a better way to run SQL queries during tests? Am I fundamentally doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@JeffBowman is right about the NodeJS requirement. So you can shift the database call to a [task](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task), which runs in NodeJs. This is a rough guide:

**cypress.config.js**

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress'
import Database from "./cypress/support/test_data/utilities/database";
const database = new Database();

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('task', {
        dbQuery(query) {
          return database.query(query)  // promise unwrapped by Cypress
        },
      })
    },
  },
})
```

```js
it('test', () => {
  cy.task('dbQuery', 'select * from Users')
    .then(results => {
      // checking my results here...
...
```

Comment: Doh, silly me. I deserve the down votes. You've been a great help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Your component requires Node, so it cannot be tested or consumed within Cypress's in-browser JavaScript environment.

---

[Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) is a *front-end, browser-based* testing framework. [`mssql`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) is explicitly for Node.JS and is not expected to work in a browser. Though Cypress's runner is in Node, and its config file you write is evaluated from Node, the test itself is run within the browser that Cypress starts for your test.

Though your code doesn't explicitly call `util.promisify`, it is very likely that `mssql` or its dependencies will do so, and that will fail in a browser environment because [util.promisify](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html) is an API offered by Node that is not a part of the JavaScript standard implemented in browsers. When your test file imports your database file, you effectively try to run that code from Cypress's browser, which is what causes your error message.

In some other circumstances you could use a "[polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Polyfill)" or "shim" to provide [an implementation](https://github.com/browserify/node-util) for a non-Node environment like Cypress's browsers, but I don't recommend trying that here: It is likely that there are many other Node-specific parts of `mssql` that make it poorly-suited for browser-based testing. Unfortunately, it is very likely that components you write that consume `mssql` cannot run within the Cypress browser environment, regardless of whether they are a part of your test setup or system under test.

This means you'll need a Node-based test framework to test your `mssql`-consuming component at the unit test or system test level; LogRocket has a [list of Node test frameworks](https://blog.logrocket.com/comparing-best-node-js-unit-testing-frameworks/) but many others exist on the internet and I don't mean to provide personal endorsement to that particular one. You can still use Cypress to write an end-to-end test, but you'll do that by having Cypress access your Node.JS server such that Cypress validates the end-to-end experience and `mssql` consumption stays within the Node.JS server.

If all you need is to run queries or database setup commands from within Cypress's JavaScript, you can consult [Kopfkino's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77567747/1426891) on using [cy.task](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task), which has [documentation example code for seeding a database](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task#Seed-a-database). This works because you're importing `mssql` from within Cypress's Node.JS process in its config file, not the browser; Cypress handles passing the message between the browser and the Node process. Otherwise, you would need to consider creating a test-only server endpoint or request handler for testing that would allow your test to perform setup actions from the browser.

Comment: Doh, silly me. I deserve the down votes. You've been a great help. Thank you.